# Como usar o SELECT + WHERE do MySQL de forma dinâmica?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Preciso fazer uma busca no banco de dados MySQL, entretanto posso ter um ou mais filtros (no máximo 6) na cláusula WHERE.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table_name'
WHERE coluna_1 = 'valor_1'
```

ou

```
SELECT * FROM 'table_name'
WHERE 
     coluna_1 = 'valor_1' AND
     coluna_2 = 'valor_2' AND
     .
     .
     .
     coluna_6 = 'valor_6'
```

Consigo salvar as informações do nome da coluna e o valor a ser procurado em uma variável e depois passar no WHERE?

```
let searchBy = `${coluna_1} = ${valor_1} AND ${coluna_2} = ${valor_2}`

SELECT * FROM 'table_name'
WHERE ${searchBy};
```

Comment: Qual cliente você está utilizando? É o [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)? Se interpolar os valores literalmente assim corre grande risco de SQL Injection, o que é extremamente grave. Não deixe de **[edit]** a sua pergunta para incluir essas informações.